# C# WebApplication POST

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to POST a form using C#

I make some searches, however I couldn't code it right way (I am new in this field).

Here are my codes;

View;

```
<form>
          <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                  Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="email" id="input-username" name="Username" required autocomplete="on" />
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password" id="input-password" name="Password" required autocomplete="on"/>
          </div>

          <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>

          <button class="button button-block" id="button-login">Log In</button>

      </form>
```

Controller;

```
// GET: User
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            string username = Session["Username"].ToString();
            string password = Session["Password"].ToString();

            Service iLocationService = new Service();
            var result = Service.MemberGetLogin( username, password, "127.0.0.1" );

            ViewBag.Message = result;

            return View();
        }
```

Javascript;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$("#button-login").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Controllers/UserController/login/",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    })
    .fail(function (a) {
        console.log( a);
    });
});
```

});

What I am trying to do is POST the input values to chech the user.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this line

> string username = Session["Username"].ToString();

In your code you are trying to read the username and password values from Session variables. Who set the user name and password to Session ? You should be reading those from the posted form and use that.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string userName,string password)
{
  // do something with userName and password and return something
}
```

Also, you need to make sure that you are serializing the form, not the button clicked. I personally prefer to use the Html helper method to generate the form tag and use the action attribute value of the form in my javascript code instead of hardcoding the urls.

So in my razor view

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("login","User"))
{
    //Your existing form inputs goes here
   <button class="button button-block" id="button-login">Log In</button>
}
```

and in the script

```
$("#button-login").click(function () {
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).closest("form").attr("action"),
        data: $(this).closest("form").serialize()           
     })
});
```

Since you are doing an ajax form submit, i suggest you return a json response which your client code can parse and do further things.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string userName,string password)
{
   //if userName and password are valid
       return Json(new { Status="success"});
   // else
         return Json(new { Status="failed", Message="Invalid credentials});
}
```

and in your done callback, you should inspect this value and do further things

```
.done(function (result) {
   if(result.Status==="success")
   {
     window.location.href="/Home/Index"; // change to wherever you want to redirect to
   }
   else
   {
     alert(result.Message);
   }    
})
```

Comment: that and the names of the your inputs, Username and Password, don't match your parameter names.  I'd also give the from an explicit url and change the button to an input type=submit, just so you have some consistent html

Comment: casing of parameter name does not match. It will still work. Also he is doing an ajax form post(where he specify the url variable.) So there is no need to specify the form action value in markup. But i prefer to do that so that i can read the closest form action value instead of hardcoding.

Comment: isn't data: $(this).serialize(), scoped to the the button and not the form?  I'd explicitly get the form and serialize that element.

Comment: That is correct. I missed that part. Corrected it now. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I have done what you recommended, but I am still having this error; http://localhost:55616/Controllers/UserController/Login 404 (Not Found)

Comment: You do not need to specify the folder name (Controllers) and the  ControllerSuffix on `UserController`. See my updated answer where i am making use of the Html helpers to render the form tag

Comment: Thank you both for your help:)